# Delete an element from an array (RecoilJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

I have a form where I put a float value (1.1, 1.2, 1.9 and so on) and I want to store a bunch of them inside an array on an atom:

```
import { atom } from 'recoil';

export const valueState = atom({
    key: 'values',
    default: []
});
```

Whenever I write a value and it's checked that it's a double, the value gets added to `valueState`, however, I want to make it so if that the value I write on the form gets deleted, it also deletes the value from the `valueState` array. I tried by using `pop`, however, if I do so the program crashes. How can I do it then?

```
import { valueState as valueStateAtom } from '../../atoms/Atoms';
import { useSetRecoilState } from 'recoil';
const setValue = useSetRecoilState(valueStateAtom);


// The function that handles the onChange event of the form
const setNewValue = (v) => {
   if (v !== '') {
      const valueNumber = parseFloat(v);
      if (!isNaN(valueNumber)) {
         setPageValueChanged(true);
         pageValue = valueNumber;
         // The value gets added to valueState
         setValue((prev) => prev.concat({ valueNumber, cardID }));
      } else {
          setPageValueChanged(false);
      }
   } else {
       setPageValueChanged(false);
       // Delete v from the atom array here
    }
};
```

Comment: how do you recognize `v` among other items in `values` array?

Comment: @NickVu By determining it's the last value added to the array, plus, I have multple forms where I input multiple flat values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pop` did not work for you because it does not return a new array (state immutability)

I think you can do a trick with `filter`. For example

```
setValue((prev) => prev.filter((value, index) => index !== prev.length - 1));
```

Full code

```
import { valueState as valueStateAtom } from '../../atoms/Atoms';
import { useSetRecoilState } from 'recoil';
const setValue = useSetRecoilState(valueStateAtom);


// The function that handles the onChange event of the form
const setNewValue = (v) => {
   if (v !== '') {
      const valueNumber = parseFloat(v);
      if (!isNaN(valueNumber)) {
         setPageValueChanged(true);
         pageValue = valueNumber;
         // The value gets added to valueState
         setValue((prev) => prev.concat({ valueNumber, cardID }));
      } else {
          setPageValueChanged(false);
      }
   } else {
       setPageValueChanged(false);
       setValue((prev) => prev.filter((value, index) => index !== prev.length - 1));
    }
};
```

One more feedback, your `concat` is seemingly incorrect. It's expecting to have an array param but you passed an object. The modification can be

```
setValue((prev) => prev.concat([{ valueNumber, cardID }]));
```